# Use Unused Repo for New Project

Tags: ios, git

I would like to save my app in one of my unused repository in GIT. Instead of creating new repo and deleting old unused repo, i want to get knowledge about Git by use the unused repo for new project.

Ex:

- old Proj repo name: app_old
- new Proj repo name: app_new

**Status of app_old:**

Am deleted all files in app_old through command. Then check out the app, the downloading status gives 80 mb done. But, there is no files in downloaded folder.

**Status of app_new:**

Created a new iOS project without checking the “Create Git Repository” option. Then choose the option “Create Working Copy” in Source Control. Then add the remote of app_old in both Xcode Preferences and Configure in Source Control.

Please adjust my English!!!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking here, but unless you need to keep the history of app_old for some reason, I would indeed suggest that you just create a new repo.

Comment: I wont want old repo data. I just reuse for new app for my study. Is It possible? How?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch Pls see my comments in answered section.

Answer (score 0):

There is not too much sense to reuse existing repository as you're going to delete it anyway.

However, in case of some constraint like reusing existing remote repo, there is a way to remove full history of git commits and start from scratch:

```
# create new branch named newProject
git checkout --orphan newProject
# do copy your new files here, set up project, set up .gitignore and things like that
...
# add all files to the project
git add -A
# commit the new branch
git commit
# delete the old master branch
git branch -D master
# rename current branch (newProject) to master
git branch -m master
# push back to origin
git push -f --set-upstream origin master
```

This way you'll get rid of old history and start from scratch with your new project.

As written in comments, you'll need to delete remote branches too if you got any.

Comment: Note that he will have to delete master on the server as well with `git push origin :master`, otherwise he will get a non-ff error when trying to push his new master. Or he could do a `git push -f`. Also he will want to delete any other branches that are on the server.

Comment: Below issue is arising when follow last steps:
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1326/1326), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1337/1337), 32.00 MiB | 4.98 MiB/s, done.
Total 1337 (delta 155), reused 8 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (155/155)
To ssh://udan@192....../IOS/app_old.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://udan@192....../IOS/app_old.git'

Comment: There is only one branch as master i had.

Comment: How could i do force push?

Comment: @UdanPirappu : Did you pull the changes from remote repo before you started? Maybe they're out of sync. Start again by cloning remote repository and continue with the steps above.

Comment: Am done some steps before ask question. The steps are: deleting all files in app_old and pushed(comment: "removing all files"), then i checkout again the app_old. There is no files in downloaded folder. In Git page, that pushed comment is showing. Is this problem?

Comment: When am trying to pull through app_new(in xcode), below issue is arised. ie. "origin/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from.

Comment: @UdanPirappu : start with freshly cloned directory: `git clone ssh://udan@192....../IOS/app-old.git local-dir` Then change dir to `local-dir` and follow the steps from answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's start from scratch. Create a new, empty directory and do:

```
git init .
git remote add origin <url of the existing repository>
git push origin :master
echo "Some text" > somefile.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master -u
```

Note the colon in the third step. Also note that if you have any other directories pointing to the old repo, you will want to delete them and re-clone from the repo.

Comment: In old repo, the tree showing only .DS_store and .gitignore.txt files only. Can i start your steps now?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -vv`?

Comment: origin ssh://udan@192....../IOS/app-old.git (fetch)
origin ssh://udan@192....../IOS/app-old.git (push)

Comment: You have to do the steps in a **brand new**, empty directory, that is itself not a subdirectory of a git repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103129/discussion-between-udan-pirappu-and-david-deutsch). Pls continue in chat.